# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
Source Error: 

Line 55:                MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(UserNameTextBox.Text);
Line 56:   
Line 57:                Object UserGUID= User.ProviderUserKey; //error appeared here
Line 58:   
Line 59:                DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());
```

I had a additional steps in createuserwizard, and upon completing the form, it would stored user info inside the DB. However this error occured :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I had also set a breakpoint to link 55, 57, 59. And from line 57, User are null, they could not get the User from the DB.

Code behind :

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {  
       MSCaptcha.CaptchaControl Captcha1 = (CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Captcha1") as MSCaptcha.CaptchaControl);

       TextBox txtCaptcha = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("txtCaptcha");
       Label Captchalbl = (Label)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Captchalbl");

       Response.Write(txtCaptcha.Text); 

           Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim()); 

           if (!Captcha1.UserValidated)
           {

                Captchalbl.Text = "InValid";

               e.Cancel = true;
           } 
            else
           {
               Captchalbl.Text = "Valid";

               TextBox UserNameTextBox =
              (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");

               SqlDataSource DataSource =
                   (SqlDataSource)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("InsertExtraInfo");

               MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(UserNameTextBox.Text);

               Object UserGUID= User.ProviderUserKey; //here is link 57. 

               DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());

               DataSource.Insert();

            }
   }
```

Comment: Is `Membership.GetUser()` using a built-in provider or a custom provider?  If the latter, debug into that to determine why it's returning `null`.  If the former, check the data to see if the requested user actually exists.  (If the former, I would argue that Microsoft broke good design practices by returning `null` as a "magic value" instead of throwing an exception or providing some explicit indicator of the inability to find the requested user, but I digress...)

Comment: Have you tried to use the `CreateUserWizard`'s [`UserName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.username.aspx) instead? `Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName)`.

Comment: Hi Tim. I had tried your method, same error persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this method name is "CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser", I can see it is for the CreatingUser event because of its signature. During this event the user has not been created yet. Use the CreatedUser event for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks a million. You solved my problem. Like what you had suggested, place the Insert method into CreatedUser event, instead of CreatingUser event

Answer (score 1):

Source [Membership.GetUser Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx)

> A MembershipUser object representing the specified user. If the
>   username parameter does not correspond to an existing user, this
>   method returns null.

Check your User object to null then try to access the properties of that object. This method return null if there are no such user with specified name. try to put your code on `OnFinishButtonClick` event, hope that works for you if you are not able to access user object from membership..

```
if( User != null)
{
  Object UserGUID= User.ProviderUserKey;
}
```

Comment: Hi, If i place Object UserGUID= User.ProviderUserKey into the if statement, another error appear. it seem that they cannot define wad is UserGuid.. the error is : UserGuid not found in current context

Comment: means you have to put other code if that depend your user's provider, it was just the example to help you to understand.. happy coding.